# Add feature and release branches to git-flow

Tags: git, git-flow

We already have a couple of feature and release branches on the go that aren't currently being tracked by git flow (we've only just come across git-flow).

Is there any way to add these to git flow as they are? So they can be tracked and merged at a later date?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you mean by “git flow”?

Comment: @Chronial "git flow" is a set of shell script that accompany a popular used branching model.

Comment: @Chronial. you are great. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you prefix the existing branches with the prefix you have selected during `git flow init` you will be fine.

git flow doesn't keep track of anything, at least the nvie version doesn't

Comment: hmm it doesn't seem to be working within Sourcetree, but its ok I can do it from the command line instead then. :) Thank you.